# C - Guarantee condvars are ready for signalling

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I have a simple application that interfaces with different pieces of hardware. For each piece of hardware, I spawn a `pthread_t` against a unique monitor function, for a total of 6 threads: 1 manager thread, and 5 worker threads.

Each thread has a common initialization routine where it waits for the manager thread to wake it up via:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&mMutex, &condVar);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
```

The main thread then wakes up all of the threads by signalling them one at a time:

```
pthread_cond_wait(&mMutex1, &condVar1);
pthread_cond_wait(&mMutex2, &condVar2);
...
pthread_cond_wait(&mMutex5, &condVar5);
```

The code actually works fine, but this is because I am lucky with the timing. There is the remote but existent chance that when the main/manager thread issues `pthread_cond_signal`, that the thread is not yet done initialization. I need to find a way to guarantee that each and every condition variable has had a `wait` call made on it by its respective worker thread.

I could always create a status boolean that is set within the corresponding mutex, but I cannot atomically do both the `set` and the `wait` operation in one instruction, so far as I know. I could also make use of a `pthread_barrier_t`, but that just guarantees all the threads are one or two instructions before making their respective `wait` calls.

Is there a tried-and-true method of being certain that the `wait` call has been made, or do I need to employ some means of timed wait looping/checking?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you may be looking for a semaphore.

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the correct snippets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could always create a status boolean that is set within the corresponding mutex, but I cannot atomically do both the set and the wait operation in one instruction, so far as I know.

That's the right way to do it -- you *can* do a set and wait operation atomically, because of the way condition variables interact with mutexes.  When you do a `pthread_cond_wait()` operation, you *must* have the mutex that you pass in be locked.  If you correspondingly have that same mutex locked when you do a `pthread_cond_signal()`, the waiting thread doesn't wake up until the signalling thread unlocks the mutex.

So, the following code would do what you want:

```
// Flag indicating if the worker thread is waiting or not
bool waiting = false;
...

// Worker thread code
... do stuff ...
while (!condition_is_not_satisfied())
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    waiting = true;
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    waiting = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
...

// Signalling thread code
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if (waiting)
{
    // Worker thread is waiting -- signal it to wake up
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
}
else
{
    // Worker thread has not yet entered the wait state -- do something else
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: Any way to achieve similar behaviour without mutex? OS signals perhaps?

Comment: It's so beautifully simple. I don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: Do not use signals for synchronisation. @self From a certain point on you will fail.

Comment: @alk I don't quite follow. Is using `pthread_cond_signal` unreliable in some respect, or should I be using `pthread_cond_broadcast` instead?

Comment: You should really take spurious wake-ups into account while waiting.

Comment: @Dogbert: Please excuse my inaccurate wording! I was refering to UNIX-signals as fired via `kill()` or `raise()`.

Comment: @Dogbert: self. and alk are talking about OS signals delivered to the process like `SIGINT` (cf. [`signal(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)), which are a completely different concept from a condition variable which is signaled with `pthread_cond_signal(3)`.

Comment: @alk: That's what the `while()` loop is for.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Ups, yes sure. My tired eyes refused to scroll up more then two lines. Sry!

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Actually not. I was referring to os signals with similar functionality as pthread signal. Win example: SignalObjectAndWait() and family.

Comment: @alk I'm wasn't referring to interrupts, but os Synchronization functions.

Answer (score 1):

A condition variable should always be paired with a mutex-protected predicate.  In this case, your predicate can just be a simple flag: in the worker thread, it would look like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
while (!woken)
    pthread_cond_wait(&mMutex, &condVar);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex);
```

In the manager thread, it would look like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
woken = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&condVar);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex);
```

Here, if the manager thread acquires the mutex first, then by the time the worker acquires the mutex the flag will be set, and it won't wait at all; if the worker acquires the mutex first, then manager won't be able to acquire the mutex and set the flag until the worker has been held at the `pthread_cond_wait`.