# multithreading consumer-producer model. How do I know when a thread is not busy

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a multi-threaded application which has a producer-consumer model.

Basically I have 2 structs.

the first one is a struct which contains all the necessary information for the work to be done.

the second one is a struct which is tied to a worker thread, it contains a pointer to the first struct.

like this:

```
typedef struct worker_struct { 

    /* information for the work to be done */

} worker_struct;

typedef struct thread_specs {

   worker_struct        *work;

   unsigned short       thread_id;

   unsigned short       pred_cond;

   pthread_mutex_t      busy_mutex;
   pthread_cond_t       work_signal;

} thread_specs;
```

now this is all fine and dandy however now from my producer I know which works needs to be done and I want to link a worker thread to work to be done. My problem is that I have no idea how can I figure out if my worker thread is currently busy or not.

I have a predicate condition with a conditional wait like so:

```
while ( thread_stuff->pred_cond == 0 ) {
    retval = pthread_cond_wait( &(thread_stuff->work_signal), &(thread_stuff->busy_mutex);
    if (retval !=0 )  {
        strerror_r(retval, strerror_buf, ERRNO_BUFSIZE);
        printf("cond wait error!  thread: %u, error: %s\n", thread_stuff->thread_id, strerror_buf);
    }
}
```

Now How can I make sure a thread is not busy. If I set a variable protected by a mutex AFTER it has woken up from the signal I get a race condition as I have no guarantee that the variable gets set before my consumer checks again for waiting threads.

the only way I see what I could do is do a `pthread_mutex_trylock()` on it with the same mutex that is coupled with the conditional wait however this seems kind of expensive and not elegant.

Is there some other way, better way to do something like this, that is figure whether a thread is currently waiting at the predicate condition?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical producer-consumer relationship, producers and consumers are disconnected from each other and communicate through some shared data structure such as a FIFO queue. Producers create jobs and place them on a queue. Consumers remove items from the queue and process them. So there is no need for producers to know whether there is an available consumer. They just queue a job, and the next available consumer will pick it up.

Such a design makes it easy to add or remove producers or consumers because they can be independent of each other.

If you need some kind of signal that a job is currently processing or is complete, you would typically use some kind of signaling mechanism such as an event.

If you want to limit the number of scheduled but not yet processed work items, you would limit the size of the FIFO queue.

Comment: I see, if I use a linked list I no longer need a signal condition as I can just check if work is available?

Comment: @RG337: That's the idea. A linked list would work as a FIFO queue, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question of mine was answered quite well some time back.

[C - Guarantee condvars are ready for signalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104864/c-guarantee-condvars-are-ready-for-signalling)

It guarantees that your condvar is indeed ready to signal via a protected status boolean, which means that it is asleep. If you're just using a simple setup (ie: one condvar per thread), then you can use this to detect if a thread is asleep or not.